# How to add meta keyword with django

Tags: python, django, keyword, meta-tags

I am using below code to add meta keywords -

in view.py

```
@template_render("mysite/category.html")
def category(request, slug):
    slug = slug.lower()
    product_type = local_settings.CATEGORY_NAME_TO_ID.get(slug, False)
    if not product_type:
        raise Http404
    products = models.Product.objects.active().filter(product_type = product_type).all()
    return { 'products' : products, 'slug' : slug, 'key':'wholesale ipad, ipad with retina display, ipad mini, ipad 3, ipad 2',}
```

And in template file -

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
{%load appletrade_tags%}
{% block key %}siteTrade - {{key}}{% endblock %}
{%block title%}site Trade - {{slug}}{%endblock%}
```

But it's not reflecting. I have checked in view source there is no keyword.

But Yes,title is reflecting.

Can you please help me to find out where I am wrong ?

**EDIT :**

base.html

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% block key %}{%if page.key%}{{page.key}}{%else%}{{block.super}}{%endif%}{% endblock %}
{% block desc %}{%if page.desc%}{{page.desc}}{%else%}{{block.super}}{%endif%}{% endblock %}
{%block title%}{%if page.title%}{{page.title}}{%else%}{{block.super}}{%endif%}{%endblock%}
{%block content%}
{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using either render or render_to_response to pass a context to the template. Is the slug object appearing on the page?

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def category(request, slug):
    slug = slug.lower()
    product_type = local_settings.CATEGORY_NAME_TO_ID.get(slug, False)
    if not product_type:
        raise Http404
    products = models.Product.objects.active().filter(product_type = product_type)
    context = {
        'slug': slug,
        'products': products,
        'key': 'wholesale ipad, ipad with retina display, ipad mini, ipad 3, ipad 2',
    }
    return render_to_response('appletrade/category.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to python. Can you please highlight where I have to do changes in code for it ?

Comment: Tried but it's giving error "The view appletrade.views.category didn't return an HttpResponse object."

Comment: @HelloPython did you import the render_to_response? There should be a more detailed traceback than that.

Comment: He has forgotten to change his return statement, he's still returning that dict.

Comment: @ergusto: Yes imported. and same exception in trackback

Comment: @HelloPython Look at Limelights response. Did you make sure to change the last line?

Comment: @ergusto:Yes,Thanks.. no error now. but  still not showing meta keywords. meta tag is blank.

Comment: @HelloPython What meta keywords? Are you talking about the 'key' string?

Comment: @ergusto- Yes. Assigning it's value in template meta tag. check 3rd line in template code

Comment: @HelloPython Try putting it somewhere other than in the {% block key %}, or rename that block. It might be interfering with the value in some way. That's a total guess, but unless you've done something differently to what I outlined, it should work.

Comment: @ergusto- Yes,You are right. not workin in this block. but I have changed  {% block keyword %} still not working even directly replaced with  <meta name="keywords" content="{{key}}" /> but no luck. Can you please help me to find where it's overlapping.

Comment: @HelloPython I can't see the base template yet, did you definitely update it?

Comment: The key block in the base template hasn't been changed. Are you sure you changed it in both templates? If you override the block in the child template, the code you already have in the base template will be overridden. Are you sure that's what you want? Try defining a new empty template block, put it in the child template, and then put the {{ key }} variable there. Best way to check if it's a problem with the template block, or the variable itself.

Comment: @HelloPython Sorry, but I can't do that. I recommend you just use stackoverflow. I can't answer questions all the time, and there are people here with more knowledge than me who will be more helpful in some situations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to **automate keywords for your django site**.  I don't like manually entering things anyways.

Here's a function to read your template file and count primary words, and return the list of the words used in the page.

```
# meta_gen.py
# create meta keywords for webpage automagically
# MIT License
# Author: Daniel P. Clark 6ftdan@gmail.com
import collections, string, StringIO, re
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

# Counts words in template files and insert keywords into page
word_count_min = 2
word_length_min = 4

nogo_list = [] # Optional list of words you may not want as meta tags.

# meta_keywords ( html string ) => 
#   returns non html keyword list, as a comma seperated string,
#   for words fitting qualifications as chosen above.
def meta_keywords(str_file):
    c = collections.Counter()
    strIO_Obj = StringIO.StringIO(str_file)
    for line in strIO_Obj.readlines():
        c.update(re.findall(r"[\w']+", strip_tags(line).lower()))
    wordlist = []
    for word, count in c.most_common():
        if len(word) > (word_length_min-1) and count > (word_count_min-1) and word not in nogo_list: wordlist.append(word)
    return string.join(wordlist, ',')
```

Place meta_gen.py in your main project folder.  Then add these pieces to each of your views.py files.

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from project.meta_gen import meta_keywords

this_template = "apptemplate.html"

def tabs(request):
    return render_to_response(this_template, { 'title' : "Page Name", 'keys' : meta_keywords(render_to_string(this_template)) })
```

And lastly in your main template base.html you place the meta tag for keywords.

```
# base.html
<head>
<title>Site Name - {{ title }}</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ keys }}" />
</head>
```

And that's it.  All pages that inherit the base template and have the views.py code will insert keywords meta tags with words that repeat on your pages.

I realize that this can be improved upon and optimized.  Speed isn't a concern for me.  So input is welcome.

Comment: Really awesome, I was looking a dynamic way to generate my keywords and this idea seems quite perfect, I will use it also to generate keywords from my models !