# Django - facebook meta tags

Tags: jquery, python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using [aldryn-facebook](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-facebook) on my Django web site, so far I am only working in a staging enviroment at aldryn.com.

I have created a facebook app, which seems to be outputting correct data when I check the https://graph.facebook.com/ap_id_xxxxxxxxx

On my blog posts, generated using aldryn-newsblog, I have included a like and share button.

I had to create my own share file, this was not included in the aldryn-facebook.

```
{% include "aldryn_facebook/snippets/_jssdk.html" %}

<div class="fb-share-button" 
    {% if instance.href %} data-href="{{ instance.href }}" {% endif %}
    data-layout="{{ instance.layout_style }}" 
    {% if instance.ref %} data-ref="{{ instance.ref }}" {% endif %}
    {% include "aldryn_facebook/snippets/_common_attrs.html" %}>
</div>
```

When I click the share button, included in the blog post, I do get the facebook share pop-up window, but with no "og-meta" tags included.

So to my question... Is there a way to dynamicly generate these "og-meta" tags? Should the aldryn-facebook handle this in live? Or must I include these in addition? If so.. could I use javscript/jQuery somehow like this, to include in the DOM for each blogpost? (Have not found a way to escape the curly brackets in the template tag)

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<meta property="og:title" content="{{ article.title }}" />';
```

Is there a Python way?

Will facebook pick up on this?

Comment: add the og-meta tags in your HTML header with a template block and  default values

Comment: Thank you for answering! Could you give me an example?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944503/how-to-add-meta-keyword-with-django and http://dustinfarris.com/2012/07/05/facebook-meta-tags-using-django-and-jade.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I tried to use jquery as well but then I realize that I could use jinja on the header like this.

```
<meta property="og:title" content= {% if article %} '{{article.title}}' {% else %} "Default page title" {% endif %} />
```

Everytime I have an article variable, like in a blogpost, it takes its title instead of the default.